# Integrating an array that returns the same size array instead of a tuple in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, integration

My apologize for the lengthy title. I have been working on a project for a a while and i'm in a rut for a certain part in my code. Ill do my best to be thorough.

I have an numpy array of masses, M, of size and shape 167197.

```
## Non-constant
M = data['m200'] # kg // Mass of dark matter haloes

R = [] # Km // Radius of sphere 
for masses in M:
    R.append(((3*masses)/(RHO_C*4*(3.14))**(1.0/3.0)))
```

I have fitting function with independent values of k that are part of my question. k is defined value in my code.

```
def T(k): # Fitting Function // Assuming a lambdaCDM model
    q = k/((OMEGA_M)*H**2)*((T_CMB)/27)**2
    L = np.log(euler+1.84*q)
    C = 14.4 + 325/(1+60.5*q**1.11)
    return L/(L+C*q**2)

##############################################################################

def P(k): # Linear Power Spectrum
    A = 0.75 # LambdaCDM Power Normalization
    n = 0.95 # current constraints from WMAP+LSS
    return A*k**n*T(k)**2
```

## *** For the actual problem ***

I have a Fourier transfrom W(kR)

[image]

```
def W(R):# Fourier Transfrom of Top Hat function
    return (3*(np.sin(k*R)-(k*R)*np.cos(k*R)))/(k*R)**(3)
W_a = [] 
for radii in R:
     W_a.append(W(radii))
```

In this condition, i'm treating R as the independent value instead of kR combined

printing the length of W_a gives me the exact same size as mu numpy array, so all is well.

This function will play a part for a integral along with the is included in this function of sigma

[image]

```
def sigma(R): # Mass Varience
    k1 = lambda k: k**2*P(k)*W(R)**2
    norm1 = 1/(2*np.pi**2)
    return (integrate.quad(k1, 0, np.Inf))
sigma_a = []
for radii in R:
    sigma_a.extend(sigma(radii))
```

The integral will create a tuple, of course. But for each value inside R. I'm wanting to create a list, or an array. So, when using `.extend()`, the length of my array is now doubled with a length of now 334394.

How do i correct it to where the integral evaluates each R in W(kR) returning an array of the same size, 167197?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just a Python note:

```
R = [] # Km // Radius of sphere 
for masses in M:
    R.append(((3*masses)/(RHO_C*4*(3.14))**(1.0/3.0)))
```

can be expressed as:

```
R = [((3*masses)/(RHO_C*4*(3.14))**(1.0/3.0)) for masses in M]
```

In:

```
return (integrate.quad(k1, 0, np.Inf))
```

the outer set of () doesn't make a difference.

```
return integrate.quad(k1, 0, np.Inf)
```

should return the same thing.

Now where does the doubling come from?  In the `quad` docs we see it returns 2 values,  the integeral and an error term.  That's shown as a tuple in some examples, but it is also unpacked in others:

```
y, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1, args=(3,))
```

If you want just integral, and not err, you could index, `integate...()[0]`.

```
sigma_a = []
for radii in R:
    sigma_a.append(sigma(radii)[0])
```

or

```
sigma_a = [sigma(radii)[0] for radii in R]
```

or

```
def sigma1(R): # Mass Varience
    k1 = lambda k: k**2*P(k)*W(R)**2
    norm1 = 1/(2*np.pi**2)
    y, err = integrate.quad(k1, 0, np.Inf)
    return y # return just the integral

sigma_a = [sigma1(radii) for radii in R]
```

If you want to collect both `y` and `err`, but in separate lists, use `zip*` to repack them (something like the numpy transpose).

```
ll = [sigma(radii) for radii in R]
# [(y0,err0),(y1,err1), ...]
ys, errs = zip(*ll)
```